# Does the SQS daemon make new connections to the app past the set limit while waiting for existing ones to return a response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) for Elastic Beanstalk worker environments one can set the number of concurrent connections of the SQS daemon to the EBS app. Suppose the app has accepted the connection within the `Connection timeout` period, but it's taking long to return a response say ~5 minutes, does the daemon keep pulling new messages and attempting to establish new `HTTP connections` or does it wait for the `Inactivity timeout` of existing ones to pass first?

I'm trying to limit the number of requests the app is processing at any given time, so when I set `HTTP connections` to `10` and have `2` instances running, I expect to see no more than `20` messages in flight. But at a certain time it reached `41`. Any ideas why and how to achieve the above?